# Cat several thousand files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have several(60,000) files in a folder that need to be combined into 3 separate files.
How would I cat this so that I could have each file containing the contents of ~20,000 of these files?

I know it would be like a loop:

```
for i in {1..20000}
do
cat file-$i > new_file_part_1
done
```

Comment: Must your output files contain the contents of consecutive input files (e.g. output1 contains input1, input2, ..., input20000)?

Comment: Warning `{1..2000}` is a zsh trick. Prefer `\`seq 1..20000\``

Comment: @Vash2593: it's perfectly valid Bash. It's isn't valid in the Bourne shell, but that isn't what he's using. (`seq`, on the other hand, is specific to GNU.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing:

```
cat file-$i > new_file_part_1
```

Will truncate `new_file_part_1` every time the loop iterates.  You want to append to the file:

```
cat file-$i >> new_file_part_1
```

Comment: @Jcrow06 It is courteous to click the tick if you think this answers solves your problem.

Comment: I know I am sorry it was not allowing me to tick the box until after a certain time limit!

Answer (score 4):

The other answers close and open the file on every iteration. I would prefer

```
for i in {1..20000}
do
    cat file-$i
done > new_file_part_1
```

so the output of all `cat` runs are piped into one file opend once for all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it doesn't matter which input file goes to which output file:

```
for i in {1..60000} 
do 
  cat file$i >> out$(($i % 3))
done
```

This script uses the modulo operator `%` to divide the input into 3 bins; it will generate 3 output files:

- out0 contains file3, file6, file9, ...
- out1 contains file1, file4, file7, ...
- out2 contains file2, file5, file8, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

cat file-{1..20000} > new_file_part_1
```

This launches `cat` only once and opens and closes the output file only once. No loop required, since `cat` can accept all 20000 arguments.

An astute observer noted that on some systems, the 20000 arguments may exceed the system's `ARG_MAX` limit. In such a case, `xargs` can be used, with the penalty that `cat` will be launched more than once (but still significantly fewer than 20000 times).

```
echo file-{1..20000} | xargs cat > new_file_part_1
```

This works because, in Bash, `echo` is a shell built-in and as such is not subject to `ARG_MAX`.

Comment: This has the potential to generate a longer command line than the maximum allowed.

Comment: @chepner: I originally included `xargs` for this in my answer, but removed it because I felt it distracted from the main point of my answer which is that using a loop is an unnecessary extra step. Adding `xargs` to this is trivial.